# How to use ffllush(stdout) in c?

Tags: c, fflush

I know about `fflush(stdin)` that it is undefined behavior according to standard. But when it comes to `stdout`, there is no such restriction. I did google to get the concept of using `stdout` as a parameter of `fflush`, but I couldn't get it.

Can someone elaborate the `fflush` function having `stdout` as a parameter with an easy example?

Answer (score 0):

When printing (e.g. `printf`), the output is put into a buffer and may not be written to the console until a newline character is displayed. To ensure that everything in the buffer is written to the console, `fflush(stdout)` may be used.

One example is displaying the progress of some process:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
       <...calculation...>
       printf("."); // Print a dot after each iteration to show progress
       fflush(stdout);   // The dot may be buffered. This ensures that it is displayed immediately
   }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't really get the example,wouldnt the printf  just print the dot immediately just like it does for printing other things? I don't see the point of fflush here.

Comment: @blake Not necessarily. As far as I know the behavior is not standardized, but it is not uncommon for `stdout` to be line-buffered such that output is inserted in a buffer and not written to the screen until a newline is encountered. Hence whether or not the `printf(".")` results in a dot being printed immediately is system-dependent. Flushing `stdout` ensures consistent behavior at the cost of a possible performance penalty.

Comment: ah that makes sense ,thanks for the reply.